# GraphicsGrid $\to$ Beep "The shared stylesheet "Stylesheet-review-topics.nb" could not be \ found. The default stylesheet will be used instead."

Tags: graphics, files-and-directories, stylesheet

12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)

I have a notebook in which using GraphicsGrid causes a beep "The shared stylesheet "Stylesheet-review-topics.nb" could not be found. The default stylesheet will be used instead."

I copied the entire content of the notebook to a new one, set the style sheet to the one shown, and saved over the original notebook.  Same thing happens. I created a new notebook and set the style sheet to the one shown, and it does not beep.  My notebooks are fairly large, and I really don't want to spend a lot of time untangling what amounts to a nuisance.  I also doing like being annoyed.

This kind of think happens from time to time, and I'm never sure why.  Any ideas?

Comment: "I really don't want to spend a lot of time untangling what amounts to a nuisance. I also don't like being annoyed" - I recommend that you stop using any computer program whatsoever then ;-)

Comment: I've programmed in more languages than you can name.  I'm trying to do productive work, and not troubleshoot.

Comment: How do you set the stylesheet and where is the stylesheet located? I am assuming that it works initially and does not the next time you start Mathematica, correct?

Comment: @Kuba The stylesheet works fine, other than the beep every time I use GraphicsGrid, in this particular notebook.  I could try to copy out parts of the notebook until I have a working notebook.  Usually that's what I do in situations like this.  But it never explains why the problem happens.

Comment: It will be tough to help without a small working example, in this case e.g. a small notebook and a stylesheet that could be tested. It can also be that this is a peculiarity of 12.0.0 as X.0.0 releases do not have a good reputation.

Comment: That's the point.  I created another notebook, and used the same stylesheet, and it didn't happen in that notebook. It happens to some notebooks, some times, and I never know why.